# SSIS Update and Delete Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Table A is imported from Excel file into SQL Server. There is serious of Update and Delete operations performed on the Table to replace certain columns with certain values. I have written a Proc for this but Since I'm beginning to use SSIS I need to know if this can be accomplished via Execute SQL Task or by using any other transformation.

Comment: You can definitely execute your stored procedure using an execute sql task.  If the procedure returns a resultset that you are trying to get into your dataflow, you can also use an OLE DB source control to execute the procedure.  If you need to include parameters, you can find a many helpful blogs on the subject, like [this one](http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2009/03/05/mapping-stored-procedure-parameters-in-ssis-ole-db-source-editor.aspx).

Comment: The issue with that is the Proc is run at the beginning of Data flow. I want the updates delete being performed by the Proc to be done on the fresh data that is loaded. When I use the proc in the execute task there was no changes in the destination table

Comment: You might have to break things up into more than one dataflow.  Do your import work first and start a new dataflow after all that is done start the next dataflow with your proc.  Use a precedence constraint to ensure that the proc doesn't execute before your load is complete.

Comment: Are you doing the Update delete operations in the table? If so then use and execute SQL task to perform those in the table then simply use an OLEDB source to select from that table to your Excel destination.

Comment: Yes I had the same idea of having dataflow for the import and a separate dataflow for operations on the freshly loaded tables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is achievable by either the slowly changing dimension component, or lookup components but both of the these require a RBAR (row by agonising row) update to be executed. If you have a small amount of data < 50,000 records) this is probably OK but it just doesn't work for larger datasets

When using the lookup or SCD components, the dataflow is split into an insert and and update stream. The insert stream is reasonably fast, but the update stream needs to be fed into an execute SQL task, which performs an update one data row at a time.

This is in contrast to the ELT method where you execute one UPDATE statement which performs all updates in one batch. This is generally much faster.

If you decide not to use the SSIS RBAR approach, you can stage your Excel data then use an execute SQL task (in the control flow) to call your existing SP. In this way a batch update can be performed rather than an RBAR one.

Comment: The data is over few million records. I will include to dataflow one for loading n one for operations. I will have precedence on it. I have worked on Informatica the entire process would have been so much simpler there. But anyways it also comes with adv n disadv as well!!

Comment: I actually don't see any reason to use the RBAR execute SQL target in SSIS. If you have a working method why move to SSIS?

Comment: SSIS is solely used for importing of flat files. The Dbs were MS Access and now will be SQL

Comment: Anyway that's my thoughts... perhaps you should try the SSIS way and draw your own conclusions. I just see SSIS being overused for things it's not very efficient at.

Comment: Yes I'm doing most of the tasks in SSMS not relying much on SSIS fo r now.